# Why won't my images appear on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, object, html5-canvas, prototype, drawimage

I want to draw many different sized circles with the same image on them using a prototype. The problem is, the circles don't appear with the images drawn on them.

The circles are still there because they're visible when stroke is used, but the images aren't drawn. I was able to have an arc be drawn with an image in it without the prototype but as soon as I use it, it doesn't work.

No bugs appear in the console, so it is not clear to me what I'm missing. 
I've tried moving the event listener outside the prototype but the circle images still did not appear.

If anyone has any insight and perhaps a solution as to why this isn't working that they can share, that would be very much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
class Balls {
  constructor(xPos, yPos, radius){
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.radius = radius;
  }
}
Balls.prototype.render  = function(){
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'crystal.jpg';
  ctx.arc(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2)
  ctx.stroke(); 
  ctx.clip();
  img.addEventListener('onload', function(e){
    ctx.drawImage(img, this.xPos - this.radius, this.yPos - this.radius, 
    this.radius*2, this.radius*2);
  });
};
let object = new Balls(100, 100, 50);
object.render();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: I am not sure this will fix the issue, but if you are using a class you can just add the render method to it and you don't need the prototype. The image might not be drawing because of CORS - where are you loading the image from? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, i just changed 2 things here in order to make your code work.

1. `load` is used for eventlistener instead on `onload`.
2. use Arrow function in order to rely on the parent context instead of dynamic context(`this`).

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
class Balls {
  constructor(xPos, yPos, radius) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.radius = radius;
  }
}
Balls.prototype.render = function() {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150.png?text=vijay'
  ctx.arc(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.clip();
  img.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, this.xPos - this.radius, this.yPos - this.radius,
      this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);
  });
};
let object = new Balls(100, 100, 50);
object.render();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had two issues in your code. Firstly, the `onload` event should be `load`. Secondly, `this` is not known inside the event listener function, so `this.radius` etc. are all undefined and `ctx.drawImage(img, this.xPos - this.radius, this.yPos - this.radius, 
    this.radius*2, this.radius*2)` doesn't work.

I used some variables for `this.xPos`, `this.yPos`, `this.radius` that can be used inside the event listener callback function.
Hope this helps!

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
class Balls {
  constructor(xPos, yPos, radius) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.radius = radius;
  }
}
Balls.prototype.render = function() {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random';
  var xPos = this.xPos, yPos = this.yPos, radius = this.radius
  ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.clip();
  img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    console.log("load")
    ctx.drawImage(img, xPos - radius, yPos - radius, 
    radius*2, radius*2);
  });
};
let object = new Balls(100, 100, 50);
object.render();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative way you can load images which is more modular, If you are making a game an `Img` class will come in handy.

`Off-topic -
if you want to load multiple images then you can add a`totalLoaded`counter to keep track of how many images has been loaded and if the`totalLoaded`count is equal to`totalImages`count then you can call a callback which will fire the animationLoop and preloads all the images.`

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

// Img class to provide modular code
class Img {
  constructor(src, x, y, size) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.src = src;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = this.src;
    this.isLoaded = false;
    this.img.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
      this.isLoaded = true;
      this.draw();
    });
  }

  draw() {
    if (this.isLoaded) {
      ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
    }
  }
}

class Balls {
  constructor(xPos, yPos, radius) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.radius = radius;
  }
}
Balls.prototype.render = function() {
  let imgx = this.xPos - this.radius;
  let imgy = this.yPos - this.radius;
  let imgr = this.radius * 2;
  let url = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150.png?text=Better';
  const img = new Img(url, imgx, imgy, imgr);
  ctx.arc(this.xPos, this.yPos, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.clip();
  img.draw();
};
let object = new Balls(100, 100, 50);
object.render();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```